Getting Google site reviews with Python
I need to be able to get Google site reviews by there API do put them in our data warehouse.
I tried with the following code:
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
service = build('**mybusiness**', 'v4', developerKey=API_KEY)

location_id = 'locations/xxxxxxxxxxxx'

# Request reviews
reviews = service.accounts().locations().reviews().list(parent=location_id).execute()
# Print review data
for review in reviews['reviews']:
    print(f"Review: {review['review']}")
    print(f"Rating: {review['starRating']}")
    print('---')

But I get an error that mybusiness v4 does not exist:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<PythonBin>\Lib\runpy.py", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<PythonBin>\Lib\runpy.py", line 88, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "<PythonBin>\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "<PythonBin>\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main        
    run()
  File "<PythonBin>\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file    
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "<PythonBin>\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<PythonBin>\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "<PythonBin>\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\src\DownloadGoogleReviewToDWH - test 2.py", line 4, in <module>
    service = build('**mybusiness**', 'v4', developerKey=API_KEY)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<PythonBin>Python312\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<PythonBin>Python312\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 304, in build  
    content = _retrieve_discovery_doc(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<PythonBin>Python312\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 417, in _retrieve_discovery_doc
    content = discovery_cache.get_static_doc(serviceName, version)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<PythonBin>Python312\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery_cache\__init__.py", line 72, in get_static_doc
    with open(os.path.join(DISCOVERY_DOC_DIR, doc_name), "r") as f:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '<PythonBin>\\local-packages\\Python312\\site-packages\\googleapiclient\\discovery_cache\\documents\\**mybusiness**.v4.json'

I found the information that the mybusisness module is deprectated but still supported, so after all it should work? Ok, I found information that I should use mybusinessbusinessinformation
service = build('**mybusinessbusinessinformation**', 'v1', developerKey=API_KEY)

# Request reviews
reviews = service.accounts().locations().reviews().list(parent=location_id).execute()

# Print review data
for review in reviews.get('reviews', []):
    print(f"Review: {review['review']}")
    print(f"Rating: {review['starRating']}")
    print('---')

Now I get an error that "'Resource' object has no attribute 'reviews'":
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<PythonBin>\Lib\runpy.py", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<PythonBin>\Lib\runpy.py", line 88, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "<PythonBin>\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main        
    run()
  File "<PythonBin>\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file    
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "<PythonBin>\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<PythonBin>\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "<PythonBin>\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\src\DownloadGoogleReviewToDWH - test 2.py", line 9, in <module>
    reviews = service.accounts().locations().reviews().list(parent=location_id).execute()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'reviews'

I began reading the documentation but I did not find anything on where to find reviews.
https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/accounts.locations
Did anyone have the same issue and found a solution to this?

You cut out all important parts from the first error traceback.

@KlausD. I added the complete stacks for both exceptions
